# XML Parsing in Oracle

Tags: sql, xml, oracle, xmltype

I am trying to parse an XML text. It is stored in a table t_testxml, in column xml_data which is CLOB type.

The xml looks like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<defaultmpftest:defaultmpftest xmlns:defaultmpftest="http://test.com"
 test_id = "1231"
 test_name = "name_test">
</mpftestdata:additionalLinkUrl xmlns:mpftestdata="http://test2.com"/>
</defaultmpftest:defaultmpftest>
```

How can I extract the values for test_id and test_name ?

I tried:

```
Select extract(xmltype.createxml(t.xml_data),'//defaultmpftest:defaultmpftest/@test_id').getStringVal() from t_testxml t;
```

But is not working. I get the following error:

```
ORA-31011: XML Parsing failed
LPX-00601: Invalid token in defaultmpftest:defaultmpftest/@test_id
```

Can you please give me some advices on this matter ?

Thank you !

Comment: What you've posted as your raw XML is invalid, as pointed out in an answer, but if run as shown you'd get a different error - LPX-00231, before it has a chance to hit LPX-00601. Removing the stray `/` at the start of the inner node name would make the XML valid and would then give the error you showed. It's helpful to show what you are actually using. [See how to create an MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The XML shown in the question is invalid, and would cause an "LPX-00231: invalid character" error if you passed it in to XMLType. So that isn't the string you're actually using. I'm assuming is a typo when posting the question, and you are actually getting the "LPX-00601: Invalid token" error you claimed. So I'll base this on that assumption, and on a string without that typo.

[`extract` is deprecated](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/functions060.htm); but even so, to use it here (with corrected raw XML) you need to specify the namespace with the optional third argument:

```
select extract(xmltype.createxml(t.xml_data),
  '//defaultmpftest:defaultmpftest/@test_id',
  'xmlns:defaultmpftest="http://test.com"').getStringVal()
from t_testxml t;

EXTRACT(XMLTYPE.CREATEXML(T.XML_DATA),'//DEFAULTMPFTEST:DEFAULTMPFTEST/@TEST_ID','XMLNS:DEFAULTMPFTEST="HTTP://TEST.COM"').GETSTRINGVAL()
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
1231
```

Rather than using the deprecated function, you could use [`XMLQuery`](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/functions249.htm):

```
select xmlquery(
  'declare namespace defaultmpftest="http://test.com"; (: :)
   //defaultmpftest:defaultmpftest/@test_id'
  passing xmltype.createxml(t.xml_data)
  returning content).getStringVal()
from t_testxml t;

XMLQUERY('DECLARENAMESPACEDEFAULTMPFTEST="HTTP://TEST.COM";(::)//DEFAULTMPFTEST:DEFAULTMPFTEST/@TEST_ID'PASSINGXMLTYPE.CREATEXML(T.XML_DATA)RETURNINGCONTENT).GETSTRINGVAL()
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
1231
```

You would need two XMLQuery clauses to get both values. I'd usually use [`XMLTable`](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/functions253.htm) instead, shown here with the (fixed) XML-as-string provided via a CTE:

```
with t_testxml(xml_data) as (select '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<defaultmpftest:defaultmpftest xmlns:defaultmpftest="http://test.com"
 test_id="1231"
 test_name="name_test">
<mpftestdata:additionalLinkUrl xmlns:mpftestdata="http://test2.com"/>
</defaultmpftest:defaultmpftest>' from dual
)
select x.test_id, x.test_name
from t_testxml t
cross join xmltable(
  xmlnamespaces('http://test.com' as "defaultmpftest"),
  '//defaultmpftest:defaultmpftest'
  passing xmltype(t.xml_data)
  columns test_id number path '@test_id',
    test_name varchar2(30) path '@test_name'
) x;

   TEST_ID TEST_NAME                     
---------- ------------------------------
      1231 name_test
```

[Read more about using these functions](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e23094/xdb_xquery.htm).

Comment: Thank  you! Very useful! It helped.

Answer (score 1):

The XML is not well-formed, try

`<mpftestdata:additionalLinkUrl xmlns:mpftestdata="http://test2.com" />`

or

`<mpftestdata:additionalLinkUrl xmlns:mpftestdata="http://test2.com"></mpftestdata>`

Comment: Thank you for the answer, but I can't change the XML. And I need information from the upper node. defaultmpftest:defaultmpftest

Comment: Provided data **is not a XML**. Thus you cannot use any XML function. You have to use REGEXP functions in this case.

Answer (score 1):

As Wernfried Domscheit correctly stated: Your XML is not well-formed. And for non-well-formed XMLs there's no way to extract information thereof in regular ways. Simply because regular ways are for XML; and your "XML" is not really an XML.

Let's try non-regular ways then...

```
with t_testxml as (
    select q'{<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<defaultmpftest:defaultmpftest xmlns:defaultmpftest="http://test.com"
 test_id = "1231"
 test_name = "name_test">
</mpftestdata:additionalLinkUrl xmlns:mpftestdata="http://test2.com"/>
</defaultmpftest:defaultmpftest>}' as xml_data
    from dual
)
select xmlcast(xmlparse(content regexp_substr(T.xml_data, '<defaultmpftest:defaultmpftest[^>]+')||' />').extract('*/@test_id') as integer) as test_id
from t_testxml T
;
```